# jQuery scroll to scroll correct position

Tags: jquery, scroll

We use some jQuery to make our navigation sticky from some point on the page and to add an active class to sections on the page.
But when we click on a anchor URL, this does not scroll to the correct position.
It scrolls to far down, and not to the correct position.

I copied our complete code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yb8kksxq/

We use this jQuery:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.menu-header-product'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 50) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.content'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 50) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
            }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('nav a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: Did u exclude your header height while scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sdghasemi** is right just the solution--

```
your page has a fixed menu header which appears on scroll.
just subtract the height in your js

**change on line 30 of your js code**

$('html, body').stop().animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-130 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
 }, 500, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
});
```